# Getting rid of hidden Ubuntu files after uninstalling Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, files

Just earlier on today, I have uninstalled Ubuntu as I didn't like it that much, so I uninstalled it. Back on windows, I check my hard drive and it seems as there is about 5GB taken from something, I believe that uninstalling Ubuntu didn't get rid of all the files since the uninstaller was finished in about 2 seconds. Is there a manual way to get rid of those files or some alternative way? Thanks!

Comment: How did you do the installation? I am assuming wubi from your question. What version of Ubuntu? What version of windows? what makes you thing the missing files are due to Ubuntu ?

Comment: Does not matter I rebooted my computer and the files then got erased somehow .. But thanks for trying to help anyway

Answer (score 2):

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_manually_uninstall_Wubi.3F

> How do I manually uninstall Wubi?
>
> Remove C:\ubuntu and C:\wubildr*
>
> In Windows XP you need to edit C:\boot.ini and delete the Ubuntu/Wubi line. Alternatively you can modify the boot menu via Control Panel > System > Advanced > Startup and Recovery and pressing "Edit". For Windows 98 you have to edit C:\config.sys and remove the Wubi block. For Windows Vista/7, you can use the built-in bcdedit command or install EasyBCD to edit the boot menu. To use bcdedit, run cmd.exe as an administrator, then enter bcdedit to show all boot entries, note the {GUID} specified for the Ubuntu entry, and then remove it: bcdedit /delete {GUID}
>
> To remove Wubi from the add/remove list, delete the registry key: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
>
> An easy method of removing this registry key is to paste the following text into a plain editor such as Notepad, close and save the file as something like removeWubiKey.reg (you may wish to go to Folder Options > View and disable the "Hide file extensions for known file types" option to check that the .reg extension has been applied correctly). Then you can perform the rest automatically by opening the file in the normal Windows manner, or choosing the "Merge" option from the right click context menu. Note: The formatting is rather strict, so copy the text exactly for best results. You may need to be logged in as the administrator to delete the key, depending on the version of Windows you are using. User Account Control in Vista may also ask for permission, in the typical fashion.
>
> REGEDIT4
>
> [-HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi]
>
> After deleting the registry key, Ubuntu may still appear in the program list. If this is the case, you may be asked if you would like to remove the item from the list.